# Is 'subject-predicate form' to be used as countable or uncountable noun?

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Willard Quine writes about Kant's formulation of an analytic statement that 'it limits itself to statements of subject-predicate form'. In this context I want to ask a question about the form - what is it? But I am not sure how to formulate the question in correct grammar. Quine does not use 'the', other people use. I feel like to use 'the' in the context, but I am not sure. 
What question would be  more correct:

- 'What is subject-predicate form?'
- 'What is a subject-predicate form?'
- 'What is the subject-predicate form?'

Comment: Is _form_ countable or uncountable? "Subject-predicate" is only a modifier here.

Comment: You can pass the buck by asking the question like this. "In the context of the writing of Willard Quine, what is 'subject-predicate form'". By putting the term in quotes, you indicate that you are quoting directly from Willard Quine, and anybody who disagrees with your choice of determiner should take the matter up with Mr Quine, and not with you..

Answer (score 1):

The word *form* has the following meaning:

> [MASS NOUN]The structure of a word, phrase, sentence, or discourse.

It is uncountable in this meaning.

An extract from Philosophy dictionary reads

> analytic/synthetic — A contrast originally introduced by Kant between types of proposition. An analytic proposition is one where the concept of the predicate is ‘contained in’ the concept of the subject. ‘All brothers are male’ is an example.